# Interacting with command prompt via Java

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to pass parameter and command to the command prompt via Java.

I am trying to create a program which gel serveral command prompt application together.

I have tried using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
```

but i can only execute one command at a time how do i pass parameters ?

Thanks.

Comment: Passing parameters to a process is easy, but I suspect what you're really asking is how to submit commands to a running shell and interact with the output, waiting after submitting one command until it is complete and the shell prompts, and then sending the next command, etc.  THAT is extremely difficult due to the large variety of conditions you must handle.  Entire large systems (such as "expect") have been written for this purpose.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, in cmd i will execute a process , after completion of the process it will ask for my password. I can execute the process from java but how do i enter my password when it asked for it.

Comment: You probably cannot do that. The password prompt is sent directly to the console device, which does not exist here, and not stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the source code of Runtime.Class.
There are several optional functions could be used like

`public Process exec(String cmdarray[]) throws IOException {
    return exec(cmdarray, null, null);
    }`

You could put commands in an array as the parameter of the function.
Hope it would be helpful for you.